# Connect AndroidThings to adb via ethernet cable

Tags: adb, iot, raspberry-pi3, android-things

Quick question. It is possible to get adb via ethernet cable connected to my laptop instead of connecting to router?

Comment: quick answer: yes. _i'm sure I read someone discussing this somewhere_ You have to get your laptop to assign it an ip

Comment: and you very likely need a point-to-point ethernet cable, which has a slightly different wiring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible, though it's a bit more work. Here are a couple of options:

1. Run a DHCP service on your laptop to assign the board an IP address.
2. Connect to the board over serial and assign a static IP address.

If the ethernet port in your laptop doesn't autocross, you may need to connect the devices using a crossover cable instead of a patch cable.

**DHCP Service**

- Ubuntu: Use a local service like [avahi-daemon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/avahi-daemon.conf.5.html).
- Mac OS: Enable [internet sharing](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25327) on the Ethernet port.
- Windows: I have never tried, but others have used [DHCP Server for Windows](http://www.dhcpserver.de/cms/) for this purpose.

**Static IP**

1. Use the [serial debug console](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html#serial_debug_console) instructions to connect a serial cable and access the shell.
2. Connect the Ethernet cable between the board and your computer.
3. Run the following command as root (replace `x.x.x.x` with a real IP address):

   `ip addr add x.x.x.x dev eth0`
4. Verify that the IP address was set properly with `ifconfig`
5. Run `adb connect x.x.x.x` or `adb connect Android.local`

The static IP address will only stick as long as the Ethernet link is active. If the device reboots or ethernet is unplugged, you'll have to run this procedure again.